# Azure app service executes container continously

Tags: azure, docker, azure-app-service-plans, azcopy, azure-appservice

I am using the Azcopy tool to copy a storage account to another. But the requirement is that the customer wants the azcopy done via some other Azure service like Azure Runbook but not the Hybrid Runbook. I have used a Docker image with azcopy. I am using Azure App Service with the docker container option. The issue is that the command executes multiple times and also once every 5 mins. How to avoid this. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds (on the surface) like your container does its job and quits, which means it is getting restarted by app service. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yeah, actually it should just execute the process and stop butt the app service restarts it. How to avoid it?

Comment: App Service *will* make it restart. That makes sense because it generally is for web apps. If it crashes you want it to restart. So now you have two options: 1. Modify your container to idle wait (remain "running" even when not doing anything), or 2. Use another service. Consider container instances - it can be configured to not restart. You'd have to figure out an external way to configure the scheduling though.

Comment: If you just want to run it once, definitely look at ACI.